# How can I show different Views in their corresponding tabs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, tabs

It doesn't matter which tab I click on, it doesn't show anything. I want to show the View in its corresponding tab. I don't know what to put between  `<div id="tab...">**HERE**</div>` to show the View (see complete code bellow)

The View looks like this:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Random stuff", "TabbedIndex?claimed=false", "Stuff", null, new { name = "tab1" }) </li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Special stuff", "TabbedIndex?claimed=true", "Stuff", null, new { name = "tab2" }) </li>
</ul>

<div id="content"> 
    <div id="tab1"></div>
    <div id="tab2"></div>
</div>
```

This is my script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); // Hide all content
        $("#tabs li:first").attr("id", "current"); // Activate the first tab
        $("#content #tab1").fadeIn(); // Show first tab's content

        $('#tabs a').click(function (e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current") { //detection for current tab
                return;
            }
            else {
                $("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); // Hide all content
                $("#tabs li").attr("id", ""); //Reset id's
                $(this).parent().attr("id", "current"); // Activate this
                $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for the current tab
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution, I didn't change anything in the original code and script:

```
<div id="content"> 
    <div id="tab1">@{ Html.RenderAction("TabbedIndex", "Stuff", new { claimed = false }); }</div>
    <div id="tab2">@{ Html.RenderAction("TabbedIndex", "Stuff", new { claimed = true }); }</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both tabs are hidden at load time, you can try this:

```
<script>
    $('#tabs a').click(function (e) 
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var name = $(this).attr("name"), tab = $("#" + name);
                if (tab.is(":visible")) {
                    //if the tab is visible, do nothing
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    // show the selected tab and hide all the siblings/neighbours tabs
                    tab.show().siblings().hide();
                }
            });
</script>
```

Comment: The first tab is what the user will see.

Comment: It should work the same anyway. You are hiding the second time in the Ready function. This code will check if the tab is visible, if it is, do nothing, otherwise show it and hide the siblings.